# Tschüssikowski, Schmakowazki und..?

Tags: idiom

Das höre ich mal als Wortspiel:

- Tchüssikowski als Abschied (Tschüss)
- Schmakowazki (wie lecker schmecker)

Beide "Nachnamen" deuten polnische Herkunft an.

Gibt es weitere "Landsleute" der beiden?

Am Rande: und wie kommts zu Stande (im Sinne, gibt es hierfür einen Fachbegriff)?

Comment: Solche Wortspiele gibt's genug. Ich verweise mal auf *Olga Kommruffufsofa*, die russische Nymphomanin.

Comment: Rainer Zufall, Klara Korn, Karl Toffel, Theo Rettich, Alice Klar, Peer Vers.

Comment: Janka, Tora, habe meine Frage präzisiert. Ihr habt super Beispiele gebracht aber sozusagen andere "Herkunftsländer".

Comment: Welche Nachnamen? Ich seh keine Nachnamen. Wie kommts zu Stande? Jemand spielt mit der Sprache, andere finden es lustig und verbreiten es - wo ist die Frage? Wieso die Sprachpolizei nicht eingreift und sowas unterbindet?

Comment: @userunknown  Wärest du mit der polnischen Kultur und Sprache vertrauter, sähest du Nachnamen hier durchaus.

Comment: @user unknown die Frage ist nach mindestens einem weiteren Beispiel welches sich fügt. Fügung muss formalisierbar sein.

Comment: Sowohl ergänzend als auch anstelle von Tschüssikowski sowie als Antwort darauf  kenne ich noch "Bis Baldinski"

Comment: Top :) passt super

Comment: Fragen in der Art »Gibt es weitere Beispiele?« passen schlecht ins Modell von SE, denn es könnte jede, die noch eines weiß eine Antwort hinzufügen, was das ganze ein bisschen ad absurdum führt. Die Frage nach der Herkunft halte ich allerdings für spannend.

Answer (score 1):

Hier ist noch ein "Nachname", der in deine polnische Reihe passt:

> Der Maulwurf Grabowski

Das ist ein Bilderbuch für Kinder (von Luis Murschetz) mit einem Maulwurf, der durch Bauarbeiten von seiner schönen grünen Wiese vertrieben wird. Nach einigen Abenteuern findet er eine neue Wiese.

Ein gutes Buch! Wenn du Kinder hast, kauf es Ihnen!

PS:

[image: Abbildung aus Luis Murschetz, Der Maulwurf Grabowkski]

(Hier noch für ganz Sprachfremde: Grabowki ist ein existierender polnischer Name, aber der Maulwurf heißt so als Spiel mit dem Tunwort "graben". Nur falls das nicht klar sein sollte.)

Comment: Bewirbt die Bahn ihre Baustellen nicht mit einem Maulwurf mit Schutzhelm und Warnweste?

Comment: @Janka   Das tut sie. Aber sie nennt ihn nicht Grabowski, meine ich.

Comment: Es würde mich - rein sachlich - interessieren, was einen der geschätzten Leser dazu bewogen hat, diese Antwort hinunterzuvotieren... ?

Comment: Welche Worte/Aussagen entsprechend der Reihe werden mit Grabowski denn wie bei den zwei anderen substituiert?

Comment: @J.Doe  Du hast in der Frage nicht gefordert, dass der polnische Name/Pseudoname als Substitut für ein deutsches Wort dienen soll. Gefragt hast du nach "Wortspiel" und "polnische Namen". Der Maulwurf Grabowski erfüllt genau diese in der Frage erwähnten Kriterien.

Comment: Tschüssikowski und Schmatzowatzki sollen ja gerade keine Namen sein, sondern nur so klingen. Genaugenommen ist Grabowski auch ein deutscher Name (Jürgen G., Eintracht Frankfurt, Weltmeister 1974, Tor gegen Schweden). Siehe auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruhrpolen (Schimanski).

Comment: @Geiselmann doch, schon, wie beschrieben: Tschüsikoeski für Tschüss.

Comment: Er gräbt, also ist 'Grabowski' doch eigentlich passend.

Comment: @Janka Der von der Bahn heißt *Max Maulwurf*, wenn ich mich recht erinnere.