# Gängige Verballhornungen im Alltag

Tags: idiom, oral-communication

Es gibt eine Reihe von scherzhaften Verballhornungen von Ausdrücken aus dem deutschsprachigen Alltagsleben wie etwa

> **Herrgott Sack Zement** (statt *Herrgott Sakrament* - ein Fluch)
>
> **Tschüssikowski** (statt *Tschüss*) <sup>1</sup>
>
> **Eau reservoir** (statt *au revoir*, auf Wiedersehen - nur für Leute mit einer gewissen Frankophonie, aber die gibt es ja auch im Deutschen)
>
> **Nimm dir selbst, dann nimmt dir Gott** (bei Tische; als Verballhornung von "Hilf dir selbst, dann hilft dir Gott")
>
> **Ich verabscheue mich** (statt "Ich verabschiede mich")

Ich würde gerne solche Alltagssprachspielereien sammeln. Kriterium wäre, dass sie nach Möglichkeit über einen minimalen Nutzerkreis (1-2 Personen) hinaus verbreitet sind.

Ich lege dies darum als Community Wiki an.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Siehe [Tschüssikowski, Schmakowazki und..?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/47966/tsch%c3%bcssikowski-schmakowazki-und)

Answer (score 8):

### Sammlung Eurer Beispiele von Verballhornung von Ausdrücken im Alltagsleben:

#### Alberne Verballhornungen

- Sei fruchtbar und Meerrettich! (statt *Seid fruchtbar und mehret euch!*)
- Prostata! (statt *Prost*)
- Zum Bleistift (statt *zum Beispiel*)
- Zum Bleifisch (dito; möglicherweise Metaverballhornung)
- Aller Unfug ist schwer (statt *Aller Anfang ist schwer*)
- Xundheit, Xaver, Xälzbrot! (Statt *Gesundheit!* - so im Schwäbischen verbreitet)
- Schönheit! (statt *Gesundheit!*)
- Märchensteuer (statt *Mehrwertsteuer*)
- Mahlzahn! (statt *Mahlzeit!* - vorwiegend bei Zahnärzten in Gebrauch)
- Bunsenrepublik (statt *Bundesrepublik*)
- Buntsreblik (dito; ironisiert die oft nachlässige Aussprache des Worts bei Politikern)
- Der Parteifotzende (statt *der Parteivorsitzende*; auch dies als böswillige Wiedergabe schludrig-schneller Aussprache des Worts durch Parteifunktionäre, v.a. aus dem Pfälzer Raum)
- Reblublikaner (statt *Republikaner*; aus der Zeit als diese noch eine relevante Partei in Deutschland waren, ca. 1990er)
- Landesmädchenanstalt (statt *Landesmedienanstalt*)
- Mädchenpolitik (statt *Medienpolitik*)
- Zisivilation (statt *Zivilisation*)
- Rechtsverdreher (statt *Rechtsvertreter*, z.B. ein Anwalt)
- Das passt wie der Faust aufs Gretchen (statt *die Faust aufs Auge*)
- Farbferngrillgerät (statt *Farbfernsehgerät*)
- Die Flinte ins Klo werfen (statt *Die Flinte ins Korn werfen*)
- Den Sand in den Kopf stecken (statt *Den Kopf in den Sand stecken*)
- Spezialdemokraten (statt *Sozialdemokraten*)
- gefickt eingeschädelt (statt *geschickt eingefädelt*)
- Mineralsekretär (statt *Generalsekretär*)
- Generalsekret (statt *Generalsekretär*)
- Da hast du wohl einen Weckstaben verbuchselt! (statt *Da hast du wohl einen Buchstaben verwechselt*)
- Meine Dinger sind zu fick (statt *Meine Finger sind zu dick* - Rechtfertigung für Tippfehler in Smartphone-Postings)
- Rot ist Blau und Plus ist Minus. (statt *Rot* ist *Plus* und *Blau* ist *Minus*)
- Reden ist Schweigen, Silber ist Gold (statt *Reden ist Silber, Schweigen ist Gold*)
- Sanitöter (statt *Sanitäter*)
- lebensähnliche Ehegemeinschaft (statt *eheähnliche Lebensgemeinschaft*)
- Papyrussieg (statt *Phyrrussieg*)
- Syphilisarbeit (statt Sisyphosarbeit)
- Bronchialgewalt (statt *Brachialgewalt*)
- Ratzefummel (statt *Radiergummi*) [oder gibt da noch eine andere Herleitung?]
- dem schnöden Mammut frönen (statt *dem schnöden Mammon frönen*)
- Katasylator, Kasalytator (statt *Katalysator*)
- Tel-Aviv, Mondamin (statt c'est la vie, mon ami)
- Das kann doch wohl nicht Warzenschwein (statt *Das kann doch wohl nicht wahr sein*)
- Oh, wie ramontisch! (statt *romantisch*)

#### Umdeutungen: Verballhornungen mit ernstgemeinter neuer Aussage

- Sprache der Richter und Henker (statt Sprache der Dichter und Denker)
- Was lange gärt, wird endlich Wut (statt *Was lange währt wird endlich gut*)
- Seid furchtbar und wehret euch (statt *Seid fruchtbar und mehret euch*)
- Ehrlich währt's am längsten (statt *Ehrlich währt am längsten* - zur Frage, wie man es zu Reichtum bringen kann; ein sehr subtiler Unterschied in der Formulierung)
- Kleider machen Bräute (statt *Kleider machen Leute*)
- Liebe geht durch den Wagen (statt *Liebe geht durch den Magen*)
- Der Scheck heiligt die Mittel (statt *Der Zweck heiligt die Mittel*)
- Gelegenheit macht Liebe (statt *Diebe*)
- Buch- und Bett-Tag (statt *Buß- und Bettag*, ein kirchlicher Feiertag im November)
- Aller Mannfang ist schwer (statt *Aller Anfang ist schwer*)
- Im Alter nützt auch Torheit nichts (statt *Alter schützt vor Torheit nicht*)
- Torheit schützt vor meiner Alten nicht (dito)
- Der Krug geht so lange zum Mund, bis man bricht. (statt *Der Krug geht so lange zum Brunnen, bis er bricht.*)
- Ein Mann, ein Wort. – Eine Frau, ein Wörterbuch.
- Viele Biere verderben den Koch. (statt *Viele Köche verderben den Brei.*)
- Man kann auch ohne Spaß Alkohol haben. (statt *Man kann auch ohne Alkohol Spaß haben.*)
- Glaube kann Sätze verbergen (statt *Glaube kann Berge versetzen*)
- Auch Zwerge haben klein angefangen (statt... tja... was? *Auch Riesen haben klein angefangen*?)

#### Religiös motivierte Umlenkungen des Wortlauts

- Kruzif...ünferl! (statt *Kruzifix!*)
- Her...kules! (statt *Herrgott!*)
- Oh Je...gerle (statt *Oh Jesus* - vermute ich jedenfalls mal; ob "Jegerle" dabei ein "Jägerle" sein soll?)
- Himmel, Sack Zement (statt *Himmel, Sakrament.*)

#### Umlenkungen aufgrund allgemeiner Anstandsregeln

- Schei...benkleister (statt *Scheiße!*)
- Schei...benwischer (dito)

#### Verballhornte Slogans, Werbesprüche und andere Wendungen

- Der Mann ist tot, die Witwe kichert: "Hoffentlich allianzversichert!" (Spöttische Einbettung des gleichlautenden Werbespruchs eines großen Lebensversicherungsanbieters)
- Herr Jesu Christ, sei unser Gast und erkläre, was du uns bescheret hast! (Tischgebet, statt *Herr Jesu Christ, sei unser Gast und segne, was du uns bescheret hast*. So gehört bei einer evangelischen Pfarrersfamilie.)
- Eigentum und Recht und Freiheit (statt *Einigkeit und Recht und Freiheit*, aus der bundesdeutschen Nationalhymne)
- Maggi Kleistermasse (statt *Maggi Meisterklasse*)
- Kentucky schreit Ficken (statt *Kentucky Fried Chicken*)
- Döner macht schöner

#### Umdeutungen aus Unwissenheit und mangelnder Zweitsprachkenntnis

- Unter aller Kanone (von *sub omni canone*)
- Hokuspokus (von *hoc est enim corpus meum*)
- Ballermann (von *balneario* - Badeort/Spa)
- Webseite (von *website*)
- Hals- und Beinbruch (von jiddisch *hatslokhe u brokhe* – Glück und Segen)

Comment: Please do not comment on a Community Wiki Answer. Add missing items or correct errors simply by editing. Thank you.